# Flask-Socketio : Unable to print within event handlers

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a chat application. I am using Flask-SocketIO and Flask-blueprints.

My js code is like this:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000/aptitude/startAptitude");
console.log("connected");

socket.on("connect", function () {
  socket.emit("my event", {
    data: "User Connected",
  });
  console.log("socket is on");
  var form = $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let user_name = $("input.username").val();
    let user_input = $("input.message").val();
    console.log("form data is", user_name, "  ", user_input);
    socket.emit("my event", {
      user_name: user_name,
      message: user_input,
    });
    console.log("socket emitted");
    $("input.message").val("").focus();
  });
});
socket.on("my response", function (msg) {
  console.log("responese", msg);
  if (typeof msg.user_name !== "undefined") {
    $("h3").remove();
    $("div.message_holder").append(
      '<div><b style="color: #000">' +
        msg.user_name +
        "</b> " +
        msg.message +
        "</div>"
    );
  }
});

</script>
```

and routes.py in the blueprint is like this:

```py
from RecruitmentService import socketio as sc
from RecruitmentService import app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_socketio import send, emit
mod = Blueprint('aptitude', __name__ ,template_folder='templates')

@mod.route('/getAptitudeQuestions', methods=['GET'])
def getAptiQuestions():
  questionset,answerset = getQuestions()
  return Response(json.dumps(questionset), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    
@mod.route('/startAptitude', methods=['GET','POST'])
def startAptitude():
  # return "Hello world"
  print("--------------------------------------------")
  print("socket is,", sc)
  return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
  print('message was received!!!')

@sc.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
  print("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
  print('received my event: ' + str(json))
  sc.emit('my response', "im here", callback=messageReceived)
  return "yes"
```

When I run the application, I see the console statements as :

```
connected
startAptitude:30 socket is on
startAptitude:35 form data is sender    chat message
startAptitude:40 socket emitted
```

But the print statements given within the event handler are not printed in the terminal. I'm not sure if the event is being triggered or not.

Terminal output is like this:

```
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 120-320-553
(22408) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(22408) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 52027)
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:41] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NDxwq3E HTTP/1.1" 200 349 0.001998
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:41] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NDxwq3i&sid=021dfdd91a4e4b22bb4dcfd726465c93 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.001026
(22408) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 52030)
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:42] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NDxwq4M&sid=021dfdd91a4e4b22bb4dcfd726465c93 HTTP/1.1" 200 183 0.001000
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:42] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NDxwq4o&sid=021dfdd91a4e4b22bb4dcfd726465c93 HTTP/1.1" 200 183 0.001144
(22408) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 52035)
(22408) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 52036)
--------------------------------------------
socket is, <flask_socketio.SocketIO object at 0x04CC6F90>
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:47] "GET /aptitude/startAptitude HTTP/1.1" 200 2095 0.022539
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2020 19:14:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=021dfdd91a4e4b22bb4dcfd726465c93 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 5.763522
```

Any help would mean a lot. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try the `logging` module??

Comment: What is logging module?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html -- I don't know if it'll be any different, but it might be worth trying to see whether the logging module logs anything for you. Try `import logging ; logging.error("Hello!")` where prints aren't working and see if anything shows up?

Comment: Nope! It dint work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to your Socket.IO server you normally don't use a URL, you just connect to the server, letting the system use the default endpoint:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
```

This confuses a lot of people, but when you add a path, Socket.IO treats it like a [namespace](https://socket.io/docs/namespaces/), not a route.

So what's happening is that your client is connecting on a custom namespace, but your server is listening on the default namespace, so the events never trigger.